# Create a list of FileInfo in PowerShell script for testing

Tags: powershell, pester

I have a PowerShell script that I want to test using [Pester](https://pester.dev/). For that I want to mock the `Get-ChildItem` like that

```
$expected = [System.Collections.Generic.List[System.IO.FileInfo]]::new()
$expected.Add([System.IO.FileInfo]::new('SmokeTest.txt'))
```

Now, I want to try a filter based on the `CreationTime`. I tried to create a file like that

```
$expected.Add([System.IO.FileInfo]::new({ 
    Name = 'Smoke Test.txt'
    CreationTime = [DateTime]::ParseExact('2023-01-01 22:00', 
        "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", $null) 
}))
```

but I get an error

> Validate files to delete.validate files with date.should return a list of expected files (mock) 8ms (8ms|1ms)
> ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.
> MethodInvocationException: Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "Illegal characters in path."

I googled but I can't find how to create a `System.IO.FileInfo` with the `CreationTime`.

Comment: The error is because the [`System.IO.FileInfo` constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo#constructors) only supports a `[string]` (path). Anyways, you might consider to use this [`ConvertTo-Expression`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ConvertTo-Expression) to build a mocking template: `ConvertTo-Expression (Get-ChildItem .\SmokeTest.txt)` although it doesn't create an actual `[System.IO.FileInfo]` type but a `[PSCustomObject]` lookalike with similar properties.

Answer (score 0):

I usually write code in Visual Studio in c# and then convert.  The issue with you code is FileInfo new only has one constructor with the filename.

```
            List<FileInfo> expected = new List<FileInfo>();
            FileInfo smokeTest = new FileInfo("Smoketest.txt");
            expected.Add(smokeTest);
            smokeTest.CreationTime = DateTime.ParseExact("2023-01-01 22:00", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is thrown because the constructor only supports specifying filename as @iRon and @jdweng explained. Also, attempting to modify `CreationTime` after creating the object would fail while trying to write it to the non-existing file.

There's two ways I'd approach this:

1. Create real files in ex `TestDrive:` and modify `CreationTime`.
2. Mock using:
   `New-MockObject -Type 'System.IO.FileInfo' -Properties @{ Name = '1_TMP.txt'; CreationTime = [datetime]'2020-01-01 21:00:00' }`

Originally answered on GitHub: https://github.com/pester/Pester/discussions/2344#discussioncomment-5818176